# Analyticity of this function $\sqrt{\coth^2(a\ z) + \coth^2(b\ z) - c}$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analytic-functions

I want to determine the domain of analyticity of this function:
$$f(z) =\sqrt{\coth^2(a\ z) + \coth^2(b\  z) - c}$$
And $$c \in ]0,1]$$

Where $$a,b \in \mathbb{Z} - \mathbb{Z}^+$$ and $a , b$ finite say $a,b \in [-1000 , 0]$

---

Suppose instead i took that $$f(z)=\sqrt{\coth^2(- \ z) + \coth^2(-3\  z) - 1}$$

Letting $$w={\coth^2(- \ z) + \coth^2(-3\  z) - 1}$$

And finding when $w=0$ is that engough to find the branch points .

Is that enugh or we must see how is $Arg({\coth^2(- \ z) + \coth^2(-3\  z) - 1})$ behave ?

### If so , How can i see that ?

Ok , I Don't see where is the problem ?

If for example we have $$f(z)=\sqrt{\coth(z)}=\sqrt{\frac{\cosh(z)}{\sinh(z)}}=\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{e^{2z}-1}}$$

We get Roots $$ z= \frac{1}{2} i(2\pi n + \pi) \ \ , z \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Does that mean that we have infinite branch points ? including 0

So Where is the $\sqrt{\coth(z)} $ is Analytic ?

Than you !

Comment: Is Coth the hyperbolic cotangent? (maybe dumb question...)

Comment: Yes it is the hyperbolic cotangent .

Comment: Square roots of negatives are OK in the complex numbers, provided one takes care about branches...

Comment: So , Is this function analytic in the first Quadrant ?

Comment: I don't know... what branch of square root chosen would make a difference I guess, but I'm no expert on that.

Comment: How can you have a function without a domain? You can't. Better to call that an expression.

Comment: We know that $\coth(z)^2$ is an even function of $z$ so why the restriction $a,b \in \mathbb{Z} - \mathbb{Z}^+$? Why not any complex numbers?